# Integrating Square with Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, square

I was wondering if anyone has integrated Square with their rails projects and could point me in the right direction in that I don't see any easy to use rails tutorials to process different payments online.

I saw their [api](http://docs.connect.squareup.com/) and can get the curl commands, such as.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer Personal_Access_Token" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me
```

Though I thought there is probably a better way than doing it with those kind of commands (such as [This curl rails tutorial](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-http-requests))

Comment: Have you added the [stripe gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) to your project? The [Ruby API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#intro) are very good. I'd suggest start with the basics e.g. connecting to Stripe from the Rails console and then work integrating into your app.

Comment: @RobinFisher I have looked at stripe and that looks like the easiest solution, but the friend I am doing it for wants it to connect to his already existing square account.

Comment: Complete apologies. I read your question as saying Stripe!

Comment: I've taken a look and [this page](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/3853-square-connect-api) suggests that you can only use Square Connect through their own store at the moment and it cannot be integrated into third party websites.

Comment: Yeah, and taking a closer look at the api I noticed that it allows you to create items to sell, but I see no ability to create a transaction. I sent a message into them and if I get anything back I will update it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square now maintain a ruby gem which wraps their APIs: https://github.com/square/connect-ruby-sdk